# Countability of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

I do not understand why this set is countable
$$\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$$

Comment: What are you stuck on? Do you know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable?

Comment: yea i know that but how will that apply to this proof.

Comment: Do you know that a subset of a countable set is countable?

Comment: I did not know that, how would I prove that?

Comment: Consider $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb N$ an injection. Then, $\left.f\right\rvert_{\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]}:\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\to \Bbb N$ is an injection.

Answer (score 2):

It's well known that the intersection between a countable set and an uncountable set is countable. Intuitively, this makes sense because the intersection between two sets has size equal to at most the minimum size of the two sets that you are taking an intersection of. In other words, the size of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$ is *at most* the size of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is known to be countable.

Comment: " the intersection between two sets has size equal to at most the minimum size of the two sets that you are taking an intersection of." Sorry sorta confused on what this part means. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I mean to say that the size of $A \cap B$ cannot be larger than both $|A|$ or $|B|$. It may help to work with a finite example. Consider $A = \{1, 2, 3\}, B = \{3, 4, 5\}$. Then $A \cap B = \{3\}$, whose size is less than that of both $A$ and $B$.